# php mysql workaround without having to use UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
select * from car where carbrand = 'bmw' limit 1
union
select * from car where carbrand = 'mercedez'
```

Is it possible to combine this query without having to use Union?

Comment: So you want to get one BMW and all the Mercedez cars? Is that right? You're not specifying which BMW to select, so you'll just get the first one (in database order) each time.

Comment: yes, have you seen the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE carbrand IN ('bmw', 'mercedez') GROUP BY carbrand
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT * FROM car WHERE carbrand IN ('bmw', 'mercedez') GROUP BY CASE WHEN carbrand = 'bmw' THEN carbrand  ELSE car_id END
```

LOOK at `car_id` in ELSE condition above, put it your respective id.

Comment: hi, i need to limit bmw by 1. this query just exposes all bmw in sql

Comment: @user1594367 so you meant you want to retrieve just one bmw?? what about mercedez? if you want to retrieve only one row of each car brands, then above query should work.

Comment: no, i want to retrieve only 1 bmw and all mercedez benz. Thanks for helping